# Change text colour with bootstrap-vue navbar item-dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using `Bootstrap-Vue` to write a web page, but I have trouble changing the text colors on the `Bootstrap navbar`, especially the `b-nav-item-dropdown` tag. I have tried using `<span class="text-dark"` to wrap around the `b-nav-item-dropdown` tag but that did not work. It appeared that the variant of the `b-navbar` can only set the text color variants to either dark or light.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="primary">
  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
  <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
    <b-navbar-nav class="pl-5" inline>

      <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Electronics">
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 1</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 2</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 3</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 4</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>


      <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Sports">
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 1</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 2</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 3</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="/">Item 4</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>

    </b-navbar-nav>
    <!--Login button-->
    <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto pr-5">
      <b-button size="me">Login</b-button>
    </b-navbar-nav>

  </b-collapse>
</b-navbar>
</div>
```

My goal is to get all the text in `b-nav-item-dropdown` to change to black instead of the grey-ash color.

Comment: There's a prop-based solution in version 2. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to wrap your components with extra elements and classes, just inspect your DOM and get the rule applied to that element and change it to a custom one. i had followed that process and i get the `color` applied to  `b-nav-item-dropdown` which is `#ffffff80` applied to this selector `.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link`, So let's change it to `black` as follow :

```
  <template>
  ...
 </template>
  <style>
   .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
      color:black!important
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass your additional class in the `toggle-class` prop. For example:

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown toggle-class="text-dark" text="Electronics">
```

See https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/nav#dropdown-support for more props this component supports.